# Exclude list items that contain values from another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, filtering

There are two lists:

```
List<string> excluded = new List<string>() { ".pdf", ".jpg" };
List<string> dataset = new List<string>() {"valid string", "invalid string.pdf", "invalid string2.jpg","valid string 2.xml" };
```

How can I filter-out values from the "dataset" list which contain any keyword from the "excluded" list?

Comment: As abatishchev says, make `excluded` a `HashSet<string>`, especially if it is large.

Comment: Thanks. If we are at HashSets, I'll give this link to a descussion around this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247442/when-should-i-use-the-hashsett-type

Comment: HashSets are not useful because it's not about a difference of sets here.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
var results = dataset.Where(i => !excluded.Any(e => i.Contains(e)));
```

Comment: can't find Contains on list ?

Comment: @Choco:    using System.Linq;

Comment: I added using  system.Linq but it doesnt know exclude

Comment: @mahdi `excluded` is the name of the list that contains the items to exclude.

Answer (score 20):

```
// Contains four values.
int[] values1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// Contains three values (1 and 2 also found in values1).
int[] values2 = { 1, 2, 5 };

// Remove all values2 from values1.
var result = values1.Except(values2);
```

https://www.dotnetperls.com/except

Comment: How in the world this answer is not marked as the correct answer and did not receive the most votes ??? Obviously all the other answer are wrong because this one is superior!!!

Comment: Because it's not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=dataset.Where(x=>!excluded.Exists(y=>x.Contains(y)));
```

This also works when excluded list is empty.

Answer (score -1):

var result = dataset.Where(x => !excluded.Contains(x));

Answer (score -1):

var RemoveList = List1.select(e=>e.name).ToList();
Var Result = List2.where(e=>! RemoveList.Contains(e.name)).ToList();

Easy way to remove items from another one list similar like NOT Equals in SQL

Comment: They're not looking for equality of strings.