# How to compare items between two disordered ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 `ListBoxs` which has a set of items. The count between each `ListBoxs` can be same or different, if the count is same, I want to check if items between the `ListBoxs` are same. The items can be disordered or ordered as shown below:

```
ListBox1 = { "C++", "C#", "Visual Basic" };
ListBox2 = { "C#", "Visual Basic", "C++" };
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use HashSet:

```
var hashSet1 = new HashSet<string> { "C++", "C#", "Visual Basic" };
var hashSet2 = new HashSet<string> { "C#", "Visual Basic", "C++" };

var result = hashSet1.SetEquals(hashSet2);
```

Comment: Can I do something like : var hashSet1 = new HashSet<string>(ListBox4.Items);...???

Comment: new HashSet<string>(listBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(x => x.Value)) works for me (selecting collection of values), since HashSet has a constructor with a IEnumerable<T> argument. The result of HashSet.SetEquals is boolean.

Comment: The result of HashSet.SetEquals is boolean - it is true if sets are equal (A is a subset of B, B is a subset of A). Moreover all elements in hashset  are unique - HashSet of { "C#", "C#" } is { "C#" }. You can read more about hashset here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247442/when-should-i-use-the-hashsett-type

Answer (score 5):

You could use Linq's All function

```
var ListBox1 = new string[] { "C++", "C#", "Visual Basic" };
var ListBox2 = new string[] { "C#", "Visual Basic", "C++" };
bool same = ListBox1.Length == ListBox2.Length 
   && ListBox1.All(s => ListBox2.Contains(s));
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming these two are two listbox controls

```
if (ListBox1.Items.Count == ListBox2.Items.Count)
{
    string[] listbox1arr = ListBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
    string[] listbox2arr = ListBox2.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();

    bool flag = listbox1arr.Intersect(listbox2arr).Count() > 0;

    MessageBox.Show(flag : "Items are not same" : "Items are same");
}
```

Comment: This might be simple to experienced people but I think it will be a bit advanced for a beginner.IMO.I might be wrong.