# GetElement from HashSet<T> in O(1)

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

I write a code, but I need it to work faster, not in O(n).

```
    public T GetElementAt(int index)
    {        
        return hashSet.ElementAt(index);
    }
```

and another one

```
    public T GetElementAt(int index)
    {
        var enumerator = hashset.GetEnumerator();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
        }
        return enumerator.Current;
    }
```

Please, help me, I have no idea how to do this.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Side note: HashSet is not ordered in any sense, so picking n-th element as good as first one... Do you really need indexed access to HashSet?

Comment: If you want O(1) access to an element in an ordered collection by index, any reason not to use `List<T>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be using `HashSet<T>` for the wrong purpose.

Sets are designed for:

1. Ensuring uniqueness
2. The ability to extract all members when needed
3. Checking whether a supplied item is already a member

`HashSet<T>` does the above things, and it does them very fast. But that's pretty much all it does.

Sets are not ordered, so trying to get the *nth* value doesn't really have any meaning or use.

For what you're doing (O(1) access by numbered item offset), `List<T>` will do perfectly well.

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1249526/2609288) gives a more detailed description of what `HashSet<T>` is for.