# C# Filling Dictionary<List<T> , List<T> > from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and have learned the basics now I am trying to create crud application using Dictionary since it is better than `list<t>` because of hash algorithm lookup.

I wanted the following using `'Dictionary< List<T>,List<T> >'` or `Dictionary<key,List<property_classname>>`

- Insert values to database using dictionary.
- Update operation to database using dictionary.
- Delete operation to database using dictionary.
- Read operation to database using dictionary.

Please suggest me a tutorial for it.I searched it but didn't find even msdn [MSDN For Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xfhwa508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't satisfy my learning requirement

Apart from that I am working on a login page using dictionary as following:
    I have two `list<T>` filling from database successfully:

`List<A>` string type for all users details who are allowed to login, `List<B>` string type contains the database of ip addresses which are blocked.

I wanted to use the `dictionary< List<A>,List<B>>` in such a way that first

1. It lookup at `List<A>` and selects the user with password.
2. It lookup at the `List<B>` and checks if the current ip address of user
   is blocked or not.

For above purpose I don't get idea how to enumerate between these two 'List'
I believe it is possible msdn definition : `public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` but don't know how to do it?

Comment: The msdn link is msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xfhwa508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Have you filled the lists successfully ?

Comment: You're doing something totally wrong. There is usually no point to have a dictionary with a key of type List<>. If you want a list of users, then you'll have a list of users. Having usernames in a list that is a key in Dictionary? Can't think of any use for that. So I assume you don't really know what Dictionary is. It's not "better than list because of hash algorithm lookup", it's *different* and is to be used in places where you need it. Not as a substitute for a List.

Comment: @MairajAhmad yes I have filled list successfully

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen you may be correct but I am doing this for learning purpose since msdn suggest public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue> so I just try to achieve the same means I can use generic key and generic value for dictionary so why not list

Comment: @Aman You *can*, but there is no *reason* to. A dictionary is a key-value store. Your list of usernames would be a key. Your list of IP addresses would be a value. Your dictionary therefore has only *one* entry, so looking it up is easy. But it won't allow you to look *in the lists* in any way. They are still lists. Keys and values also have a relation to each other. Here they don't.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen think that for a particular index of a list I have UserId and as key and for the other list I have details of ip address which used by that userid

Comment: @Aman Then you would use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, if you want to have the IP addresses as strings (I would suggest otherwise). Then you add each user as a key and a separate list for the user as the IP addresses. This would be a correct way to use Dictionary.

Comment: @Aman - the design you're suggestion doesn't make any sense. `Dictionary<K,V>` should hold many keys of type `K`, not just one, that would be meaningless. If you want to learn C# you should think in classes: Have a `List<User>`. A `User` may have properties like `string UserName {get;set;}` and `List<IPAddress> BlockIps {get;set;}`. Now ask how to populate that data structure. Also, in practice, you only need to load *one* `User` for the login page, not the list of *all* users.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I am agree with you but still i love c# for reusability and generic type so I wanted Dictionary < string , List<property_classname>> is it will be good idea?

Comment: @Aman Yes, using a `List<>`as a value in a dictionary is quite ok in places where you need to have lists for some key. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Kobi you are correct i have edited the question

Comment: please read this text, it could improve your skill:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247442/when-should-i-use-the-hashsett-type

Comment: @Kobi should I remove the later part of question I was assuming that for Dictionary< K,V> K will contain only singular values like userid of user.

Comment: @W92 thanks I will surely go for it but please also provide me link for crud operations using dictionary collections.

Comment: if you have iterate throug your collection you would use list or ICollection, if you want to use it for create LINQ query - please use IQuerable (but List implements it). Dictionary can give you a way to fetch data from collection not neccessary to listen through full. Read any information about binary trees, hashset. Read an documentation of List and interfaces