# Slow LINQ missing from list query

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a pretty standard block of code that compares two lists and returns the items from the first list that are not matched in the second list. (unmatched query)

But when both the lists are large-ish, the unmatched query takes 3 minutes to execute.

```
// names.Count ~ 91k 
var names = xxxxx.ToList();

// namePhonetics.Count ~ 91k
var namePhonetics = yyyyy.ToList();

// this line takes 3 minutes to run
var namesMissingPhonetics = names.Where(n => !namePhonetics.Any(np => np.NameId == n.Id)).ToList();
```

What can I do to increase the performance of this?

Comment: What is `xxxx` and `yyyy`. Are they by chance IQueryable? Then don't `ToList()` them. Working with 91k data is not trival. If not, use a hashset.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt No they are not IQueryable. I included the ToList to note that they are indeed Lists.

Comment: Then use [hashset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247442/when-should-i-use-the-hashsett-type) as I said @rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var namePhoneticsDict = yyyyy.ToDictionary(x => x.NameId, x => x);
 var namesMissingPhonetics = names.Where(n => !namePhoneticsDict.ContainsKey(n.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Phenomenal! Thank you!